# How to remove a line in a file found in multiple directories

Tags: batch, remove, findstr

There is file that exists in each user profile directory and I need to remove the line from the file in each user profile directory. I'm using a batch script to go through each user profile directory, type the file, use findstr to not display the line, and then re-direct the output to itself. For whatever reason this is not removing the line.

```
SET ProfileBase=%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad-h "%ProfileBase%"') do type "%ProfileBase%\%%a\myfile" | findstr /v display >> :%ProfileBase%\%%a\myfile"
```

Comment: typo: "Docuemnts" -- not in your actual code, maybe?

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo here. I verified that it is correct in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Is using win32 versions of `sed` and `find` out of the question?
Those could easily do it*. Also, PowerShell might be worth a look.

*)
`find /path/to/files -type f -iname 'filename' -execdir sed -i -e '/^exact line you want to disappear$/d' {} \;`